# Is it necessary to set the base font-size when sizing with rem?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have seen multiple approaches to web typography that suggested setting the base font-size (on either the `html` or `body` element) to a precise pixel value, or a percentage (`62,5%` for example, for easy sizing with `em`, or `100%`).

I'm researching whether this is still necessary, when sizing type with `rem`. My idea is that when working with > IE9, `rem` is an easy way to size type based on the users preferred base font-size. So it is:

- Good for accessibility (i.e. not overriding the users preferences)
- Easy to design with (the values don't cascade, and the entire design can be sized up or down, so it's fluid)

But since there are so many recommendations, I'm wondering: is there something I'm missing? What is the current state of affairs regarding font-sizing? Are there accessibility concerns with my approach, things I haven't thought of? Just looking for source material that deals with this issue, from the standpoint of the current state of affairs, not opinions.

Answer (score -1):

`rem` is based on your `root` element, or `html` tag size, so giving that a size is advised. I wouldn't wonder about 'user preference', since most modern browser will just enlarge everything uniformly. So the golden rule is to set your `html` size to your base value in pixels:

```
html { font-size: 12px; }
```

simply because it's easy to calculate from there. After that, set every subsequent font value like this:

```
.element {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

It seems quite extensive, but it allows for maximum compatibility. Accessibility wise it's not a concern, as increasing size of your font in the browser will increase the original `12px` in your `html`, and will enlarge the rest subsequently.

Comment: I don't think the `font-size: 12px` declaration is needed - I can't think of any browser that would ignore the `1em` and use the `12px`. Also, your last sentence is incomplete.

Comment: @BoltClock you might be right, but it does allow me to be more in control of my output (aka, if I want something to be approximately 60px, then I know it'll be 4rem, but 5rem on its own means nothing) but true, it can be omitted. Also, my last sentence was cut off because SO decided I wasn't 'human' enough and threw and error, on reload I seem to have not noticed some content wasn't saved. I _can_ dance like a robot now, though.

Comment: So if I don't care about ease of calculation I can omit the `font-size` for the `html` element (I size everything relative to eachother, don't really care about pixel values)? If I omit that will it still be just as accessible, like you described in your last paragraph?

Comment: Okay, so the thing is, the pixelvalue in the `html` tag _is_ necessary, as it provides the base for your `root` size. (so 2rem will be `2 * html`s `font-size`). You can ommit the pixel value anywhere else. If a person enlarges the text on your site, you rootvalue will go from, say, 12px to 18px, turning every other declaration of `rem` .5 times larger. Don't worry too much about accessibility - as long as your structure is good and your site isn't based around javascript only-ness, browsers will do the heavy lifting for you. (12px does not mean 12px anyhow, that depends on the user settings).

Comment: But won't the base `font-size` just be `16px` if I don't set it? Is that not enough?

Comment: I mean, why would setting the `font-size` on the root element be necessary, if it's already set by default (and if I don't mind the default value)? Can you explain why you'd still recommend setting it explicitly?

Comment: @DrMister Because the 'default' value is not in your control whatsoever. What if Google decides tomorrow that the default for Chrome is better off being `24px`? You should always define them _to be safe_. Even if it is not required, it is good practise. Think: a developer might need to touch this twenty years from now and the defaults might be different! Just like you can't rely on `h1` elements looking the same _by default_ everywhere.

Comment: Ok, now I see why we're disagreeing on this. See, I don't mind the browser or user setting the default. If I design my site around rem values, it'll always look good, because the elements are sized relative to eachother. The only thing that will change if the font becomes larger for example, is that the elements will all be bigger. The site won't break. So I don't need the control, and am putting it where it belongs, in the users hands.

Comment: @DrMister If you don't 'need' the control you don't care about UI or UX. Users can resize as resizing is a _factor_ and not a _default_ value. You should make the sure the site works at the size you define (as the designer of the site you are responsible for the UX and UI at a certain size) and allow other users to upscale when needed without breaking.

Comment: I disagree. I care about UI/UX, which is *exactly* why I'm not overriding defaults, or user preferences. In my design I'll make sure that by keeping it fluid, it'll look good at *any* setting. And not just the setting that *I've* chosen as the one that the user should use. They can, and should, decide for themselves. And (at least for FF), the default font setting is not a factor but a px value. Now zooming, that probably *is* a factor.

Comment: @DrMister good luck. Don't use pixels _anywhere_. Your image sizings? `REM`s please. Thats how scalable that will be.

Comment: I dont' mean to start an argument by the way, I respect your opinion. But for images for example, I'd make them fluid too. By using responsive images and `max-width:100%`.